# entering a string into the system function

Tags: c++, string, function

I want to make a program in C++ that prompt the user to enter a web address and then performs the ping command in the command prompt on that address. In the code, I used the *cin* command to get the web address into a string variable called *n* and add it to "ping" in the same variable but, I cannot enter the string into the system function. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string ping;
    string n;
    cout << "Enter the link you want to ping ";
    cin >> ping;
    n = "ping "+ping;
    cout << n;
    system(n);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I enter the string from the variable *n* into the system function?

Comment: Please, do not pass user input to the shell. Script-kiddies will find out about it. Use the proper library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) is a C function,

```
int system( const char *command );
```

it doesn't know c++ `std::string`, you could pass `const char*` to it:

update

```
system(n);
```

to

```
system(n.c_str());
```